# API returning only partial data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, mern, react-context

I'm making an API call to a product database and am getting the full response in the form of:

```
data: {
   data: [ 
      //Array of product objects
   ]
   meta: {
      pagination: { 
         //Pagination data
      }
   }
}
```

I need to dispatch the response to my reducer. When I attempt to assign the contents of data and meta (from the parent data), the data gets assigned successfully, but the meta returns as "undefined."

Here's my code with Axios:

```
axios
   .get('/api', {
      params: { //API params }
   })
   .then(res => {
      const data = res.data.data;
      const meta = res.data.meta;
      dispatch({
         type: GET_PRODUCTS,
         payload: { data, meta }
      });
   });
```

I've also tried to assign the response of axios to a constant after awaiting the axios callback:

```
const res = await axios.get('/api', {
        params: { //API params }
      });
const data = await res.data.data;
const meta = await res.data.meta;
dispatch({
   type: GET_PRODUCTS,
   payload: { data, meta }
});
```

Both result in the following responses in my React front-end:

```
res.data.data = [//Array of data objects]
res.data.meta = undefined
```

Even though the parent `res` contains the needed data for both fields.

Any idea what's happening? I'm kind of at my wits end.

Comment: Can you create a basic Github repo to reproduce the same error?

Comment: Where are you getting `undefined`? Is it right after the assignment of `const meta = res.data.meta;` or inside reducer?

Comment: Can you provide the output of res.data

Comment: @bharadhwaj I'm getting undefined in the browser console as this is the front-side Context-API handler for getting products.

Comment: @teej yeah, understood. I am asking where are you putting the `console.log()`. Inside Axios promise or inside the reducer? Also, adding a sample output of console.log will help.

Comment: @bharadhwaj Oh, I'm sorry I misunderstood. I'm putting the `console.log()` in the functional component that is being loaded by React.

Comment: @varoons `{
   data: [ 
      //Array of product objects
   ]
   meta: {
      pagination: { 
         //Pagination data
      }
   }
}`

Comment: @teej Just try to put `console.log()` after - `const meta = res.data.meta;` - this line and see what it holds? If it has the value, then you might be having issues somewhere else with the logic.

Comment: @bharadhwaj I don't know why, perhaps I was so bogged down coding, but I didn't notice the meta console output until just now (which it is getting filled with the meta data). Following the order of operations and will respond if I can't find where it's getting lost.

Comment: @teej The time when the component renders the value of meta might be undefined. The first way is to try writing the reducer correctly so that it updates props and component is re-rendered or try setting a `state` value for meta value and update the `state` value as soon as you get the meta value from API call. Updating state means, the component will be re-rendered on state changes and making meta value show in the component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208871/discussion-between-teej-and-bharadhwaj).

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I was stupidly using the wrong variable in my Context Provider. Upon updating that to the correct information, the proper data was getting sent over and loading into my interface. Thank you all for bearing with my stupidity!